# Error alert in uipickerview options

Tags: swift2, xcode7, alert, uipickerview

I'm working in these lines trying to show an "Error" message if the user forgot to fill the **username label** or choose **an option from the PickerView ("-- Choose an option please --")**, but, when I run this, it takes also the other options from the picker view as an error.

If the user choose A,B,C,D it's okay. I just want to define the first one ("-- Choose an option please --") as an error, but it doesn't works.

---

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

```
let userRole:[String] = ["-- Choose an option please --", "A", "B", "C", "D"]
var selectedOption:String?

@IBOutlet weak var usernameLabel: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var pickerRoleLabel: UIPickerView!

@IBAction func continueButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    if usernameLabel.text == "" || userRole[0] == "-- Choose an option please --" {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error in form", message: "Please fill the information", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

---

How can I improve this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This line need to be fixed.
    **if usernameLabel.text == "" || userRole[0] == "-- Choose an option please --"**.

You´re doing a kind of static comparation... **userRole[0]** will be always **"-- Choose an option please --"**.

You´re comparing the array´s position 0 with the own position 0 value...

Comment: I see. Thank you! For the other hand, what's the equivalent of "aaaa.text" for the pickerview option? If I want to save the data. It's ".text" also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always ensure your "-- Choose an option please --" string as first item. So you can just test if the value of the desired component with **UIPickerView´s** **selectedRowInComponent** method is bigger than **"0"**.
If **"0"** is returned from this method, means your first position is selected, but if you receive **"-1"**, no value was selected in your picker. Any value bigger than "0" you can considerate as a valid value.

selectedRowInComponent(_ component: Int)

```
@IBAction func continueButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    //If you

    if usernameLabel.text == "" || myPickerView.selectedRowInComponent(0) < 1 {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error in form", message: "Please fill the information", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```